# Configure logstash to ban IP address if it match several times in log

Tags: logstash

I want to configure my logstash to ban a IP address if it is matched 5 times in an logfile, but I don't know how to count how many times the IP is found, my actual config file looks like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/home/myuser/mygameserver/server_log.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "[(?<date>[.*?])] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: %{IP:clientip}" }
  }
}

output {
  exec {
    type => abuse
    command => "iptables -A INPUT -s %{clientip} -j DROP"
  }
}
```

The log output is something like this:

```
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
[17/11/2015 22:38:02] BAD RCON ATTEMPT BY: 179.214.221.81
```

I think the config file is right, I just want to put a counter on it to only execute the firewall ban if the IP address is found 5 times on log.

Comment: Seems like a combination of metric{}, threshold{} (to gather and group the data) and http{} (to hit some unknown service that would enforce the ban) might work.  If not, there's always ruby{}.

Comment: @AlainCollins Can you please detail a little bit more your solution? Sorry, I'm new to logstash. I'm searching for the functions you provide but I got no luck on tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[metrics{}](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html) will count how many items come through logstash.  It groups the counts together by the 'meter' parameter, and the doc shows how to use a variable (like your IP address) as a value.  So, this could create a new event for you, with the counts of IPs seen in a specific period.

[throttle{}](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-throttle.html) could then be used to enforce the number of times an IP address can be seen, by adding a tag when the specified count has been reached.

Now that you've counted them and applied a limit, you're ready to perform some action.  You don't describe how you might update your firewall, but logstash has an [http{} output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-http.html) that could hit some URL with the appropriate data.  This output would be conditional ("if") on the tag set by the throttle filter.

Hope that helps.